# how to exclude part of string from regex matching (arabic dictionary examples)

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have string like this:

```
var str = "translation1; translation2; اللغة العربية example1; اللغة العربية example2; اللغة العربية example3; اللغة العربية example4; اللغة العربية example5; اللغة العربية example6; اللغة العربية example7; اللغة العربية example8; اللغة العربية example9";
```

It's word translations, after them goes examples, witch I identify like arabic letters between 2 semicolons. I need to separate between translations and examples, and get array only with examples:

```
["اللغة العربية example1", "اللغة العربية example2", .... ]
```

I tried this code:

```js
var str = "translation1; translation2; اللغة العربية example1; اللغة العربية example2; اللغة العربية example3; اللغة العربية example4; اللغة العربية example5; اللغة العربية example6; اللغة العربية example7; اللغة العربية example8; اللغة العربية example9;"; 
var match = "";
var example_pattern = /;([\s\S]+?[ا-ي]+?[\s\S]+?);/ig
var examples = [];
while (match = example_pattern.exec(str)) {
                    examples.push(match[1]); 
                    example_pattern.lastIndex --; 
                }
console.log(examples);
```

But it returns examples[0] = "translation2; اللغة العربية example1;".

**How to remove "translations2;" from matching in example1?**

Rest of elements executes fine.

(I made `example_pattern.lastIndex --;` because without it code returns array only with 1st, 3d, 5th, 7th, 9th examples. May be there is a way to make regexp example_template better)

Comment: What about just [`str.match(/[ا-ي]+/g)`](https://jsfiddle.net/0vouaLe0/) to match any chunk of 1+ Arabic letters?

Answer (score 0):

It was so stupid mistake. I fixed problem just by removing \S in the beginning of regex "example_pattern"